# Get array from json flutter

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, fetch

Trying to get plant info and found https://trefle.io/ Api, to use in my flutter app, i need list of plant infos, so i found a json structure like this;

[image]

I'm trying fetch data from api array and implement it my ListView.builder, but i'm getting error;

type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

So What's the most efficient way of fetching array data from json

**List View**

```
ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: 10,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            Plant plant = Plant.fromJson(decodedData);
                            Data data = plant.data[index];
                            Container(
                              child: Image(
                                image: NetworkImage(data.imageUrl),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
```

**FETCH DATA**

```
  Future<dynamic> fetchData(String url, bool asyncCall) async {
    asyncCall = true;
    response = await http.get(url);
    decoded = json.encode(response.body);

    return decoded;
  }
```

**PLANT**

```
class Plant {
  List<Data> data;

  Plant({this.data});

  Plant.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = new List<Data>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }

    return data;
  }
}
```

**DATA**

```
class Data {
  int id;
  String commonName;
  String slug;
  String scientificName;
  int year;
  String bibliography;
  String author;
  String status;
  String rank;
  String familyCommonName;
  int genusId;
  String imageUrl;
  List<String> synonyms;
  String genus;
  String family;

  Data({
    this.id,
    this.commonName,
    this.slug,
    this.scientificName,
    this.year,
    this.bibliography,
    this.author,
    this.status,
    this.rank,
    this.familyCommonName,
    this.genusId,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.synonyms,
    this.genus,
    this.family,
  });

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    commonName = json['common_name'];
    slug = json['slug'];
    scientificName = json['scientific_name'];
    year = json['year'];
    bibliography = json['bibliography'];
    author = json['author'];
    status = json['status'];
    rank = json['rank'];
    familyCommonName = json['family_common_name'];
    genusId = json['genus_id'];
    imageUrl = json['image_url'];
    synonyms = json['synonyms'].cast<String>();
    genus = json['genus'];
    family = json['family'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['common_name'] = this.commonName;
    data['slug'] = this.slug;
    data['scientific_name'] = this.scientificName;
    data['year'] = this.year;
    data['bibliography'] = this.bibliography;
    data['author'] = this.author;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['rank'] = this.rank;
    data['family_common_name'] = this.familyCommonName;
    data['genus_id'] = this.genusId;
    data['image_url'] = this.imageUrl;
    data['synonyms'] = this.synonyms;
    data['genus'] = this.genus;
    data['family'] = this.family;

    return data;
  }
}
```

**To Solve**

Added this func below

```
 Plant plant;
  Future<void> getPlant() async {
    String url =
        'https://trefle.io/api/v1/plants?token=jAEYseuuPFUlUss9QcNOefanIBG_fb83mkXdaRDIu8w';
    Map<String, String> header = {"Content-type": "application/json"};
    // make GET request
    var response = await http.get(url, headers: header);
    // check the status code for the result
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        plant = plantFromJson(response.body);
      });
    } else {}
  }
```

**changed fetchData**

```
 Future<Plant> fetchData(String url, bool asyncCall) async {
    asyncCall = true;
    response = await http.get(url);

    final plant = plantFromJson(response.body);
    print(plant);
    print(plant.data);
    print(plant.data[0].imageUrl);
    return plant;
  }
```

Comment: I use dynamic or sometimes no type def at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    import 'dart:convert';

Plant plantFromJson(String str) => Plant.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String plantToJson(Plant data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Plant {
  Plant({
    this.data,
    this.links,
    this.meta,
  });

  List<Data> data;
  PlantLinks links;
  Meta meta;

  factory Plant.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Plant(
    data: List<Data>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Data.fromJson(x))),
    links: PlantLinks.fromJson(json["links"]),
    meta: Meta.fromJson(json["meta"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "links": links.toJson(),
    "meta": meta.toJson(),
  };
}

class Data {
  Data({
    this.author,
    this.bibliography,
    this.commonName,
    this.family,
    this.familyCommonName,
    this.genus,
    this.genusId,
    this.id,
    this.links,
    this.plantId,
    this.rank,
    this.scientificName,
    this.slug,
    this.status,
    this.synonyms,
    this.year,
  });

  String author;
  String bibliography;
  dynamic commonName;
  String family;
  String familyCommonName;
  String genus;
  int genusId;
  int id;
  DatumLinks links;
  int plantId;
  String rank;
  String scientificName;
  String slug;
  String status;
  List<String> synonyms;
  int year;

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
    author: json["author"],
    bibliography: json["bibliography"],
    commonName: json["common_name"],
    family: json["family"],
    familyCommonName: json["family_common_name"] == null ? null : json["family_common_name"],
    genus: json["genus"],
    genusId: json["genus_id"],
    id: json["id"],
    links: DatumLinks.fromJson(json["links"]),
    plantId: json["plant_id"],
    rank: json["rank"],
    scientificName: json["scientific_name"],
    slug: json["slug"],
    status: json["status"],
    synonyms: List<String>.from(json["synonyms"].map((x) => x)),
    year: json["year"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "author": author,
    "bibliography": bibliography,
    "common_name": commonName,
    "family": family,
    "family_common_name": familyCommonName == null ? null : familyCommonName,
    "genus": genus,
    "genus_id": genusId,
    "id": id,
    "links": links.toJson(),
    "plant_id": plantId,
    "rank": rank,
    "scientific_name": scientificName,
    "slug": slug,
    "status": status,
    "synonyms": List<dynamic>.from(synonyms.map((x) => x)),
    "year": year,
  };
}

class DatumLinks {
  DatumLinks({
    this.genus,
    this.plant,
    this.self,
  });

  String genus;
  String plant;
  String self;

  factory DatumLinks.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DatumLinks(
    genus: json["genus"],
    plant: json["plant"],
    self: json["self"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "genus": genus,
    "plant": plant,
    "self": self,
  };
}

class PlantLinks {
  PlantLinks({
    this.first,
    this.last,
    this.next,
    this.self,
  });

  String first;
  String last;
  String next;
  String self;

  factory PlantLinks.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PlantLinks(
    first: json["first"],
    last: json["last"],
    next: json["next"],
    self: json["self"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "first": first,
    "last": last,
    "next": next,
    "self": self,
  };
}

class Meta {
  Meta({
    this.total,
  });

  int total;

  factory Meta.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Meta(
    total: json["total"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "total": total,
  };
}
```

**response = await http.get(url);
final plant = plantFromJson(response.body) // to get parsed data**

Comment: created method, and tried plant=plantFromJson(response.body) nothing changed

Comment: final plant=plantFromJson(response.body) then use plant.data , where you get all data

Comment: What you get 
plant=plantFromJson(response.body) ;
print(plant.data);

Comment: Instance of 'Plant'

Answer (score 1):

Here what i want to say exactly

```
 Future<Plant> fetchData(String url) async {
final response = await http.get(
    "TYPE_YOUR_HTTP",
    
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  return Plant.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));//change here
} else {
  throw Exception("Failed to load data");
}
```

}

//Future Builder

```
Future<Plant> plantList;
  plantList = FetchData.fetchdata(data);//create a future object and call your fetch data funct with it
return FutureBuilder<Plant>(
      future: plantList,/
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("No result "),
            );
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.plant.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                    //Create ListTile here or something that you prefer);
              },
            );
          }
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
          return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error));
        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      });
```

Comment: wrapped with future, passed decoded data as future, and same error occurs again

Comment: Didn't try it but  solved issue with other way as you can see in my question now, thanks for your help anyway.